# What is the current most accurate model for the generation of binary black hole gravitational waveforms?

Tags: black-holes, computational-physics, gravitational-waves, models

As you know there are a lot of models to choose from, and there is constant improvement in both gravitational waveform generation and detection methods. Now some of the most used GW generation models are the IMRPhenom and SEOBNR models. Are there any newer models? If not, what are the best versions of those two models, and what are the metrics for deciding if the model is better?
https://lscsoft.docs.ligo.org/lalsuite/lalsimulation/group___l_a_l_sim_i_m_r_phenom__c.html

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms or provide links.

Comment: Which sources are you interested in? IMR and EOB models deal with compact binary coalescences, but there are also distinctions to be made there (e.g. BBH/BNS/NSBH...)

Comment: only Black Hole binaries

Comment: Appendix E of the [GWTC-3](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.03606) paper discusses waveform systematics in some detail, that's probably a good starting point. Note that in addition to the two waveform families you mention, there are also [NR surrogate models.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.07865)